# AWS Cloudfront API error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to update the Distribution using CloudFront API - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/PutConfig.html

I am adding CustomErrorResponses. So, basically what I do is

1. Get the Distribution
2. Remove if there is any CustomErrorResponses in the document
3. Add the CustomErrorResponses with appropriate error codes.

However, I am getting this error

```
<ErrorResponse
xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2015-07-27/">
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>IllegalUpdate</Code>
    <Message>The specified list of custom error responses does not exist or is not valid.</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>XXXX</RequestId>
```

I tried passing only 404 but it fails with that as well. The interesting thing is when I make POST request (create new distribution) it works fine but with PUT it's not.

It would be awesome if somone please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I need to add the "ResponsePagePath" and "ResponseCode" element in the request even though there value would be empty. So, the entry I added looks like this and it works fine

```
<CustomErrorResponses>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <Items>
     <CustomErrorResponse>
        <ErrorCode>404</ErrorCode>
        <ResponsePagePath/>
        <ResponseCode/>
        <ErrorCachingMinTTL>5</ErrorCachingMinTTL>
     </CustomErrorResponse>
   </Items>
</CustomErrorResponses>
```